# Storing and displaying images on a ASP.NET Webforms website with back end SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, image, webforms

I am building a website using ASP.NET. The site contains information about 571 houses. Each house has 10 images associated with it, 1 main and 9 others. I want to be able to store all these images in a folder and set a path to them in a SQL database. The site has over 100 pages of houses with 5 results per page when I click on a house I want it to know what house I have clicked and display the images for that specific house. I am using one aspx page with a repeater control this way I don't have multiple aspx pages and the houses are displayed and filtered using pagination. The main thing I want to find out is how to store and display these images using a SQL database. There over 5000 images, 10 per house.

Comment: If using SQL Server (2008 R2+?) it is also possible to use [FILESTREAMS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx). These are effectively 'pointers to files', but managed by the database. You'll have to write (or find) an IIS handler to return the data - then the filestreams (and associated metadata) can be handled directly in SQL.

Comment: Or .. you can just use FILESTREAMs.

Answer (score 0):

In a SQL database you should have something called `Primary Key`.
Most probably, it is an integer (it should be so).

You can create a folder (e.g. `Content/HousePhotos/`) and create subfolder for each house.

For example, for house #713 photos will be stored in:

```
/Content/HousePhotos/713/1.png
/Content/HousePhotos/713/2.png
/Content/HousePhotos/713/3.png
/Content/HousePhotos/713/4.png
/Content/HousePhotos/713/5.png
/Content/HousePhotos/713/6.png
/Content/HousePhotos/713/7.png
/Content/HousePhotos/713/8.png
/Content/HousePhotos/713/9.png
/Content/HousePhotos/713/10.png
```

If you use such directory structure, then

*First*, you can be sure that your directories are unique and existent.

*Second*, it will be pretty easy to make any CRUD operations on your "houses".

```
Create - create folder, copy photos in it
Read - easily access it by direct URL
Update - replace files
Delete - remove folder
```

*Third*, there will be no need to store images, their pathes or any other information in a database.

*Fourth*, you will be able to operate with photos as files. For example, through the FTP.

*Fifth*, the images can be properly cached by either your server and client browser. It will significantly decrease the amount of traffic and speed of page loading.

Comment: 1. Same can be done in database (and ability to have formal relations) 2. Same can be done in database (with better edge-case handling) 3. Data can be stored with FILESTREAMS for the no-files-in-DB purists; no different than encoding path in a filesystem 4. FTP?!? Anyway, now a 'control gatekeeper' (the database and/or application tier) has been lost 5. Caching can be done independent of local storage mechanism